# Convert SQL query result to Datetime - Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, type-conversion, sql-convert

I want to convert the result of this query (string to DateTime)

```
SET [something] = dbo.fn_GetProfileElement('WelcomeSent',PropertyNames,PropertyValuesString)
FROM aspnet_Profile where  aspnet_Profile.UserId = CTUsers.userid
```

so I try this:

```
SET [something] = CONVERT(DATETIME,(dbo.fn_GetProfileElement('WelcomeSent',PropertyNames,PropertyValuesString)
    FROM aspnet_Profile where  aspnet_Profile.UserId = CTUsers.userid),101)
```

But I receive this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: You forgot the `select`.

Comment: I want to SET a column with the results of this query. I updated the query

Comment: @this.lau_ when I added the select I receive this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Which is the same with the one I received when I didnt convert the query at all

Comment: Are you attempting to update a table that has a column called `something`? can you provide the code for that function? (`dbo.fn_GetProfileElement`)